# Choosing a value from each of n identical arrays, get all combinations

Tags: javascript, linear-algebra

Let's say I have 3 identical arrays, each looks like this: `[1,2,3,4]`.

By choosing a value from each array, I want to exhaust all combinations, so in this example, the desired result would be:

`[1,2,3], [1,2,4], [1,3,4],[2,3,4]`

Order doesnt matter. I'm currently iterating over every possibility, and that's waaaay too slow.
I thought about first doing a check to make sure the iterator is greater than the one to the left of it, but in the case of `1,4,...` that would fail because the 3rd array doesn't have anything bigger than 4. So additionally I'd need to do a check to make sure the max of each column is no greater than `column length - (# of repeating columns - column position`. For example column 2 could not exceed 3. But I think I'm going down the rabbit hole.

Any clever ways to get the desired result in the fewest iterations possible? Modifying the arrays is fair game, too.

Comment: I'm thinking that if you described the actual problem you're trying to solve, we might be able to come up with a better way than generating all possible combinatorials.

Comment: Is there any meaningful reason you need n (3) identical arrays? Is that somehow different than using a single array n times?

Comment: It's look like Cartesian product? ))

Comment: possible duplicate of [cartesian product of multiple arrays in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12303989/cartesian-product-of-multiple-arrays-in-javascript)

Comment: Yeah, so real-world scenario it's like a modified branch and bound. The input is anywhere from 2 to 7 arrays and each array has a certain class. The solution can have 2 results from the same class. So, for example, lets say the optimal mix consists of a Class 2, a Class 3, and another Class 3. The Class 2 array has 50 possibilities, the Class 3 has 40 possibilities. Currently I check each combo: 50*40*40, but ideally I'd only check 50*780 (where 780 is 40 choose 2). Hope this clears it up!

Comment: Stdob, yup! sorry I should've mentioned that, it is a Cartesian product I'm after, but the access pattern is a little different than anything I've been able to find.

Comment: If I understand correctly, after computing the Cartesian product is necessary to remove those vectors that have the same values for the second and third part?

Comment: Nope, removal not necessary. Currently I just iterate through using an index counter (for 3 arrays with respective classes of 2,3,3 and lengths of 50,40,40 my index counter increments the last value first so if I increment [0,0,40] it becomes [0,1,0], kinda like an old alarm clock. I'm open to new methods if I could increase performance without a huge hit to the memory.

Comment: Consider providing code you have currently. Also make sure you know how many results you actually going to compute - helpful to know if it is "slow" because your code is not optimal OR because there is just large number of results.